# Bottom of scrollbar hidden if margin-top specified

Tags: html, css

am sure there is a really simple solution to this but I can't seem to get it right. I need a margin-top of 50px on my form for my header but this seems to push the bottom arrow button of the scrollbar off the page. The only element I want to scroll is the contents of wrapper (hence the overflow-y: hidden on the body). Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

  <style>

    body{
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper
    {
        height: 100%;
        left: 225px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: green;
    }  

    #content
    {
        height: 2000px;
        background-color: red;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The overlow-y is causing the scrollbar to disappear off the page like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `height: 100%` for `#wrapper` and plus `margin-top: 50px;` will be `100% + 50px`. Set your `#wrapper` less height and everything will be fine. Or calculate height with `calc`. Like this:

```
#wrapper {
   height: calc(100% - 50px); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

basically you need to se the height of your `#wrapper` to 100% minus the margin top with something like this:

```
#wrapper {
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
         }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0cgk8adj/1/)**

Comment: Np. Glad I could help. and not really important but next time it would be much nicer if you give the credit to the answer posted first when both are the same one, anyway gl with your project

Comment: @majornorthwest I agree with Alvaro. Alesha basically copy pasted this answer. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Ty for your comment Andrew however, very often, it happens that people are answering questions right at the same time. I prefer to think this is one of those cases. it makes me sleep better at night.